# Can't get RSpec view spec to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I've got the following spec in `spec/views/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "users/new.html.erb" do 
  it "displays the text attribute of the message" do
    render
    response.should contain("Register")
  end 
end
```

But when I run the test it fails with:

```
ActionView::TemplateError in 'users/new.html.erb displays the text attribute of the message'
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

The line it is failing on is:

```
<% form_for @user, :url => account_path do |f| %>
```

In my `Users` controller for the `new` method, I have this:

```
@user = User.new
```

Any ideas why I'm getting that error?

**UPDATE: Per request, here's my routes file...**

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resource :account, :controller => "users"
  map.resources :users

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: Post updated with routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view specification is run in complete isolation from the Users controller. Thus, you have to initialize the variables needed in the view yourself, as described [here](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/views.html). The result would be something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'path/to/user.rb'

describe "users/new.html.erb" do 
  it "displays the text attribute of the message" do
    assigns[:user] = User.new
    render
    response.should contain("Register")
  end 
end
```

If you want to test your view together with your controller, I would suggest looking into integration testing with Cucumber.

Comment: In RSpec 2.8, `response` is deprecated. Use `rendered` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just a more updated answer.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "users/new.html.erb" do 
  it "displays the text attribute of the message" do
    assign(:user, stub_model(User))
    render
    expect(rendered).to include("Register")
  end 
end
```

This should work on rails 3.2.13 and rspec 2.13.0